# Find all TD tags and read their data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select all `TD` tags on the page that has a `class of hours` and read each data attribute (short name of month) and then add that value after the current content within the `<td>` and `</td>`. Like `<td>40 Dec </td>`.

Since I don't get any value, something is wrong with my script, but what have I missed or done wrong?

My jQuery:

```js
$("tbody").find("td").each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("hours")) {
        var d = $(this).data("date");
        $(this).append("<br>" + d);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
  <td data-date="dec" data-activityid="7" data-resourceid="1" data-projectid="2" class="workingHours-ok hours">40</td>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use **[`append(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-function)**, which iterate over the elements and appends the returned html code. So inside the helper function get the data attribute value and return it.

```js
$('td.hours').append(function() {
  return '<br>' + $(this).data('date');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-date="Dec" class="hours">40</td>
    <td data-date="Jan" class="hours">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-date="Feb" class="hours">60</td>
    <td data-date="Mar" class="hours">70</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-date="Jan" class="hours">60</td>
    <td data-date="Mar" class="hours">70</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `each()`. You can do it like following.

```js
$('td.hours').text(function (index, text) {
    return text + ' ' + this.dataset.date;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-date="Dec" class="hours">40</td>
        <td data-date="Jan" class="hours">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-date="Feb" class="hours">60</td>
        <td data-date="Mar" class="hours">70</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: You can avoid calling `jQuery()` again by using `text` argument of `.text(function(index, text) {})`

Answer (score 1):

Because of your **$(this).data("date")**.This is not working.You should use **$(this).data('date')**
Of course your selector should be like

```
 $("#yourtableid > tbody td.hours").each(function(){
var d= $(this).data('date');//and so on//})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `tbody` in your markup, try this

```
$("tbody td.hours").each(function () {
     $(this).append("<br>" + $(this).data("date") );
});
```

or simply

```
$("td.hours").each(function () {
     $(this).append("<br>" + $(this).data("date") );
});
```

or using simply `attr` if **data-date is set dynamically**

```
$("td.hours").each(function () {
     $(this).append("<br>" + $(this).attr("data-date") );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it is your code , as it is just add `<table>` before `<tbody>` because , in your code , a `<tobody>` is not a parent to `<td>` unless being a child of `<table>`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<table><tbody>
  <td data-date="dec" data-activityid="7" data-resourceid="1" data-projectid="2" class="workingHours-ok hours">40</td>
</tbody></table>


<script>
$("tbody").find("td").each(function () {
     if ($(this).hasClass("hours")) {
        var d = $(this).data("date");
        $(this).append("<br>" + d);
    }
});</script>
```